# Using RowMapper and JdbcTemplate got NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data, jdbctemplate

#### I have two entities - user and accessgroup. When getting user entity from MySQL database using RowMapper in JdbcTemplate I have NullPointerException. When not using setter for accessgroup in UserRowMapper I dont have NPE but have null in AccessGroup accessGroup.

**Table**

```
      CREATE TABLE `users` (
      `USER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `USER_EMAIL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `USER_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `USER_PWD` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `ACCESSGROUP_GROUP_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`USER_ID`),
      KEY `FK_users_ACCESSGROUP_GROUP_ID` (`ACCESSGROUP_GROUP_ID`),
      CONSTRAINT `FK_users_ACCESSGROUP_GROUP_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`ACCESSGROUP_GROUP_ID`) REFERENCES `access_group` (`GROUP_ID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

```
    CREATE TABLE `access_group` (
      `GROUP_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `GROUP_NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`GROUP_ID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Entities**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class User implements Serializable {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "USER_ID")
        private Integer userId;
        @Column(name = "USER_EMAIL")
        private String userEmail;
        @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
        private String userName;
        @Column(name = "USER_PWD")
        private String userPwd;
        @JoinColumn(name = "ACCESSGROUP_GROUP_ID", referencedColumnName = "GROUP_ID")
        @ManyToOne
        private AccessGroup accessGroup;
```

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "access_group")
    public class AccessGroup implements Serializable {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
        private Integer groupId;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "GROUP_NAME")
        private String groupName;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "accessGroup")
        private Set users;
```

**Dao**

```
    @Repository("userDao")
    public class UserDaoImpl implements IUserDao {
    
        @Autowired
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
        @Value("${sql.user.get.email.pwd}")
        private String getByEmailAndPwd; 
    
    //sql.user.get.email.pwd=SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = ? AND user_pwd = ?
    
        @Transactional
        @Override
        public User getUserByEmailAndPwd(String email, String password) {
            return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(getByEmailAndPwd, new Object[]{email, password}, new UserRowMapper());
        }
```

```
    @Repository("accessGroupDao")
    public class AccessGroupDaoImpl implements IAccessGroupDao {
    
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
        @Autowired
        public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
            this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        }
    
        @Value("${sql.accessgroup.get.id}")
        private String getAccessGroupById;
      //sql.accessgroup.get.id=SELECT * FROM access_group WHERE GROUP_ID = ?
    
        @Transactional
        @Override
        public AccessGroup getGroupById(int id) {
            return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(getAccessGroupById, new Object[]{id}, new AccessGroupRowMapper());
        }
```

**RowMappers**

```
    @Component
    public class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper {
    
        private AccessGroupService accessGroupService;
    
        @Autowired
        public void setAccessGroupService(AccessGroupService accessGroupService) {
            this.accessGroupService = accessGroupService;
        }
    
        @Override
        public User mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(resultSet.getInt("USER_ID"));
            user.setEmail(resultSet.getString("USER_EMAIL"));
            user.setName(resultSet.getString("USER_NAME"));
            user.setpwd(resultSet.getString("USER_PWD"));
            //when adding here user.setAccessGroup(accessGroupService.getGroupById(resultSet.getInt("ACCESSGROUP_GROUP_ID"))); I have NPE
            return user;
        }
```

```
    public class AccessGroupRowMapper implements RowMapper {
    
        @Override
        public AccessGroup mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
            AccessGroup accessGroup = new AccessGroup();
            accessGroup.setId(resultSet.getInt("GROUP_ID"));
            accessGroup.setName(resultSet.getString("GROUP_NAME"));
            return accessGroup;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Let's start with: do you know if `AccessGroupService accessGroupService` was correctly injected? Can you "inspect" `resultSet.getInt("ACCESSGROUP_GROUP_ID")`?

Comment: Well obviously it will be `null`... You are creating an instance yourself and expect Spring to inject something into it. A bean instance that isn't managed by Spring will not be injected. Why have you annotated your classes with JPA annotations but use JDBC?

Comment: It would be more useful if you have pointed out where exactly this is breaking, you have the log and you may know at which line it was breaking.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add the following property to your @Entity class 'User' & generate the getter & setter methods:

```
@Transient
private Integer userIdTransientField;
```

@Transient means the property will not be stored in the database

2) Modify RowMapper class:

Replace this line with the following :

```
user.setId(resultSet.getInt("USER_ID")); -> user.setUserIdTransientField(resultSet.getInt("USER_ID"));
```

3) When you refer to a 'User' object and you want to do a Update/Delete for jdbcTemplate or simply want to get the Id value then use the getUserIdTransientField method.